# jQuery animate: background position not animating, showing image instantly

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

There's something wrong with this code, or the way I've laid out my menu because animating the background position won't work. In my CSS I've simply assigned every a in the div.nav to have a background with 0 0 positioning as well as display: block and a specific width + height. What happens is image switch is done instantly instead of scrolling in (-95px on background positioning). What am I missing?

```
$('div.nav a').mouseover(function () {
    if (!$(this).is('.active')) {
        $(this).stop().animate({
            backgroundPosition: '0 0'
        }, {
            duration: 500
        });
    }
});

$('div.nav a').mouseout(function () {
    if (!$(this).is('.active')) {
        $(this).stop().animate({
            backgroundPosition: '0 0'
        }, {
            duration: 500
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery, natively, can't handle that properly because it needs two values to modify.

http://snook.ca/archives/javascript/jquery-bg-image-animations/

You should replace `backgroundPosition: '0 0'` with `backgroundPosition: '0px 0px'`

That should work, but it should also just animate the x-axis.

Comment: That's exactly the tutorial I began working with (I haven't used background positioning with animate before) but the end result didn't work - even if I copied the authors' code directly on to my elements. I guess one way could be to have a regular image inside the a element then use it's background property to "extend" how that image looks by another image (which is what I'm trying to achieve). Just seems unnecessary.

Comment: Aw, you know what. I missed the tiny, additional plug-in the author had created... Working perfectly now! ;)
Too bad this function requires extra code though, should be a core feature.